# Unable to use the on.() for a file upload with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So I know this should be as easy as a copy and paste from the firebase storage docs, but I honestly can't figure out why the .on() function doesn't work. For reference I can make the upload happen, but I am unable to monitor the progress of the upload. I am using react, tailwinds and firebase. I can not monitor the upload with .on() and instead just upload with .then() and the fill gets uploaded correct and I can then retrieve it somewhere else, but I want to be able to monitor the progress but for the last 3 days have been unable to figure it out... Hopefully someone can help!
(ps project is to host the photos on my website of my wedding)

firebase config

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*****",
  authDomain: "****",
  projectId: "*****",
  storageBucket: "******",
  messagingSenderId: "*******",
  appId: "****",
  measurementId: "******Y"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const proStorage = getStorage(app);
const proFirestore = getFirestore(app);

export {proStorage, proFirestore}
```

code!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {proStorage} from '../firebase/config';
import {ref, uploadBytes, listAll, getDownloadURL} from "firebase/storage"
import { v4  } from 'uuid';

const Uploadform = () => {
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(null)
  const [imageList,setImageList] = useState([])

  const upLoadImage = () =>{
    if (imageUpload ==null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(proStorage, `images/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`)     
    
    const uploadtask = uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload)
    uploadtask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    getDownloadURL(uploadtask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
    alert('Image Uploaded')
  }

  const imageListRef = ref(proStorage, "images/")
  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(imageListRef).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setImageList((prev) => [...prev,url])
        })
      })
    })
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  },[])

  return (
    <div className='absolute h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center'>
      <div className='h-[50%] w-[50%] justify-center items-center border'>
        <div className='h-full w-full flex items-center justify-center'>
          <input  type='file' 
                  onChange={(e) => {setImageUpload(e.target.files[0])}}
                  console/>
          <button className='bg-black text-white' onClick={upLoadImage}>Upload Image</button>
        </div>
        {imageList.map((url) => {
            return <img src={url} alt='imgs'></img>
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Uploadform
```

the error

```
ERROR
uploadtask.on is not a function
TypeError: uploadtask.on is not a function
    at upLoadImage (http://localhost:3000/main.271f87fd8bd9fdcb1a1d.hot-update.js:38:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45197:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45241:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45298:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45312:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49456:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49482:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49493:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49502:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49662:16
ERROR
uploadtask.on is not a function
TypeError: uploadtask.on is not a function
    at upLoadImage (http://localhost:3000/main.271f87fd8bd9fdcb1a1d.hot-update.js:38:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45197:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45241:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45298:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45312:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49456:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49482:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49493:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49502:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49662:16
ERROR
uploadtask.on is not a function
TypeError: uploadtask.on is not a function
    at upLoadImage (http://localhost:3000/main.271f87fd8bd9fdcb1a1d.hot-update.js:38:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45197:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45241:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45298:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45312:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49456:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49482:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49493:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49502:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49662:16
```

Tried using the .on() and it is reported as not a function, use .then() for the meantime but unable to track progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the [`uploadBytes()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytes) method does **not** return an `UploadTask`.

You should use the [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytesresumable) method.

Comment: You are my savior.. I have been up all night trying to think of why it wouldn't work!!!